# Can Maven ignore a missing system property?

Tags: maven, maven-2, properties, maven-3

If I have the following in my pom file:

```
<properties>
    <mySystemProperty>${mySystemProperty}</mySystemProperty>
</properties>
```

When I build using "mvn clean install -DmySystemProperty=someData", it builds successfully.  If I build it using "mvn clean install", where I don't need to specify the system property, Maven gives me this error:

```
Resolving expression: '${mySystemProperty}': Detected the following recursive expression cycle in 'mySystemProperty'
```

Is there a way to get maven to ignore the missing system property?  If not, is there a way to default it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved it.  Using the same name for the system variable and maven variable caused the problem.  Renaming the system variable fixed the error.

```
<properties>
    <mySystemProperty>${sysProperty}</mySystemProperty>
</properties>
```